# Cargo project with library + multiple binaries, with binaries consisting of multiple files?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

[The Cargo book describes how to have a library and multiple executable](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html#binaries) in a single Cargo project.

I'd like to have an executable consist of multiple source files that are specific to that executable and not in the library.

For example

- src/lib1.rs, src/lib2.rs, src/lib3.rs in the library itself,
- src/bin/exe1.rs + another source file specific to exe1 for the exe1 executable.

Where would I place this last source file so that it's not compiled into the library but compiled into the executable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Cargo-supported way to have multiple source files for a single binary in a package is to give it a directory with `main.rs`. [The documentation on “Package Layout”](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/project-layout.html) gives this example (I have removed irrelevant elements):

```
src/
├── lib.rs
└── bin/
    ├── named-executable.rs
    ├── another-executable.rs
    └── multi-file-executable/
        ├── main.rs
        └── some_module.rs
```

You want the `multi-file-executable` case here. Name the directory whatever you want the binary to be named. Your `main.rs` will then contain `mod some_module;` in just the same way as if this project had been a simple `src/main.rs` project.